# Rails 3: Convert a fixture to a set of ActionController::Parameters

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, testing, fixtures

Is there a way to covert a fixture to a set of ActionController::Parameters?

For example:

```
# contacts.yml

dan:
  first_name: Dan
  last_name: Gebhardt
  email: dan@example.com
  notes: Writes sample code without tests :/

joe:
  first_name: Joe
  last_name: Blow
  email: joe@example.com
  notes: Lousy plumber

# contacts_test.rb

@dan = contacts(:dan)
# create params that represent Dan?
@dan_as_params = ActionController::Parameters.new(???)
```

Any and all help appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could turn the object into json and back to hash containing correct param keys thus:

```
h= Hash[*JSON.load(@dan.to_json).map{ |k, v| [k.to_sym, v] }.flatten]
params= {contact: h}
```

Update:

you can also use JSON.parse

```
dan= Hash[*JSON.parse(@dan.to_json, symbolize_names: true).flatten]
params= {contact: dan}
```

Which has its own internal way of converting json keys to symbols.